# chart yAxis update error: object# has no method 'update'

Tags: highcharts

In my highchart plots I need to change some attributes of a yAxis. I can do it using update or redraw. But when I use update, it gives me error: "object# has no method 'update'".
Here is the screenshot:[http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2hmfoug&s=5]

[image]

And when I use chart redraw, it does not adjust ticks properly when there are multiple yAxis.

I have tried to create an example of the problem I am facing, Here is the example: [
http://jsfiddle.net/3MB5n/]

In the above link, In button1,  I am using a chart.redraw method and chart axis update method in button2.

With the button 1, gap between yAxis[0] ticks is changing, but it does not adjust the remaining yAxis, like it does in button 2.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to solve the above mentioned error if I use chart.redraw
2. Why I am getting error, when I use chart.yAis update in my code, and the error does not show on jsfiddle? How can I solve it in my code.

Comment: 1) Only bu using other workarounds. 2) Upgrade Highcharts to version 3.0+

Comment: Thank you, I was using old version. Upgrade solved my problem :)